# Spring cloud decrypt API

Tags: encryption, spring-cloud

I'm new to spring cloud.
The user can able to decrypt when encrypted value passes in the decrypt post API. Even a normal developer can able to decrypt the encrypted value using decrypt post API. So this is not secure.

Is there any alternative for this? 
I meant the **secret is need to pass with decrypt post API**. Then it can decrypt only who know the encrypt key and encrypted value.

Is this possible? This is my suggestion only.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. can you say what api's you are calling and with what values?

Comment: /decrypt API calling for decrypting and encrypted value passes for decrypting.

Comment: Need to know can we pass secret key while decrypting the encrypted value using /decrypt API?

Comment: Secret key has to be configured in config server

Comment: I configured spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false. Even decryption is possible. How to disable decryption?

Comment: There's not a way to disable decryption. You could use spring AOP to disable it.

Comment: What about spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false?

Comment: It does not disable those endpoints